# Migrating Joomla site to local machine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I borked a Joomla site while trying to upgrade to Joomla 3. One of the extensions was not supported and I had to restore my backup, including the backup of the database. Unfortunately, it did not work and I just got mySql errors. I should not have tested it locally instead of trying it on a production site.

Now I am trying to run a copy of the website on my computer locally, with Xampp. Xampp is running Apache and mySql. I've configured MySql according to the instructions at: http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website but I am still getting the error:

```
Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't enter your details correctly when you were setting up Joomla. http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/database/database-connection-error-2-could-not-connect-to-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your database settings in the file `configuration.php` in your Joomla root directory, this is the file that connects Joomla with your MySQL database.

When using XAMPP on your computer, the `root` user (with empty password) usually has access to all your databases.

Try setting the following variables in you `configuration.php` file:

```
public $user = 'root';
public $password = '';
public $db = 'DATABASENAME';
public $host = 'localhost';
```

(leave the rest of the fields as they are for now).

**Short explanation:**
**$host** : usually "localhost" when using XAMPP
**$user** : usually "root" when using XAMPP
**$password** : usually empty when using XAMPP
**$db** : The name of the database I assume you imported using a tool like `phpmyadmin`

Comment: changing the host to localhost on your local machine, instead of using the ubiquitously preferred explicit IP address of your loopback device, worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error means what it means.
You have defined some incorrect value for the database connection parameters.

Check your **configuration.php** file and ensure you have filled in the following variables correctly:

```
public $user = 'DB_USER';
public $password = 'DB_PASSWORD';
public $db = 'DB_NAME';
public $dbprefix = 'jos32_';
```

Also ensure that you have assigned your database user to the actual database in PhpMyAdmin